# How to avoid images to be"cropped" on facebook preview after sharing a link to the users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've been banging my head against the wall with this issue and I hope someone can help:

I have a page that I'm sharing on Facebook (currently using the js sdk / fb.ui / method: 'share'), the flow works fine, the page gets shared BUT the preview of the page on the user's wall or feed sometimes shows a square image sometime shows a rectangle image.

I have set the open graph tags properly on the page and the scraper seems to find everything fine, but I still get this inconsistency when it is displayed on user walls. Is there a way that I can specify 2 different images (one for square presentation another for rectangle)?

One more thing, the image that I have specified on the og:image tag is exactly 1200 x 630 pixels, as per the best practices docs.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Facebook will crop pictures that appear to have white space on the sides. To avoid this problem, fill the sides with a different color (like a light grey). Also sometimes the preview image seems to be cached on FB servers longer than it should be, especially if you haven't changed the filename. You can use FB's debug tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing to preview image links for any URL before you insert them.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Since you said that the image is 1200x630, there should be no problem. That being said, Facebook decides how the posts look like and there is nothing else you can do. It depends on several factors afaik (how many likes, how many spam reports, ...).

Comment: You wrote "It depends on several factors afaik (how many likes, how many spam reports, ...).", but I have products with square images 800x800px (1:1), then what should I do? Facebook is cropping the images and none can fix this?

Comment: not sure what you mean...facebook recommends using 1200x630, so why would you use square images? there is nothing to fix, just use the recommended aspect ratio.

Comment: Almost all product images on the website are square, 1:1, some of them are portrait or landscape rectangle, but I cannot resize thousands of product images. So when shared on Facebook, they are cropped and it looks bad.This way, my client is not satisfied and I have no solution to fix  this, because there is no way to control the size of the image or the position.

Comment: but those are the recommendations from facebook, there is no way around it.

Comment: Yes, I see that... I thought maybe someone has a way to customize the shared image.

Answer (score 0):

> Facebook will crop pictures that appear to have white space on the sides
>   They don't seem to do that with me. They just hack it into a square, usually centered (I'm assuming we're talking about general pics in posts, and not profile pics.)

What I've had to do is *make* the image square by adding dummy filler strips to the top and bottom for landscape pics, or to the left and right sides for portrait. I'll have to be careful if I use white filler.